# Does the setMaxListeners warning affect my discord.js code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, eventemitter, nodemon

As I was restarting my code using nodemon, I got the following warning:

```
(node:11576) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

Code: to [Ubuntu Pastebin Link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pSfNgzgjhk)

I believe this is caused by the fact that I have >10 `client.on();` scripts. Here's my logic for it: if `client` is what runs the `EventEmitter`, and each `client.on` is a `Listener`, then there would be over 10 listeners.

I've tried just putting `emitter.setMaxListeners(Infinity)`, but I get the following error (note that line numbers may not be accurate):

```
/home/discord/Desktop/channel.js:9
emitter.setMaxListeners
^

ReferenceError: emitter is not defined 
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/discord/Desktop/channel.js:9:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at Startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootsrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

What should I add to fix this? I'm worried some of my `client.on` subscripts may not work run.

Comment: 10 listeners is not much and I suggest that you should probably look for the leak.

Comment: It's not a leak

Comment: If you looked at my code I have >10 client.ons, that is what is causing it, and as such your suggestion is not useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `emitter` is your Discord.js client.
So you can use this to allow Infinity listeners:

```
client.setMaxListeners(0);
```

But this is not advisable because there's probably a memory leak somewhere in your code.